# Merge nested array in object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, lodash

I need to merge 2 objects with nested arrays

```
var dest = {
  id: "865",
  arr: [{
    id: "123",
    value: "First" }]
};

var src = {
  id: "865",
  arr: [{
    id: "456",
    value: "Second" }]

};
```

to produce

```
merge = {
  id: "865",
  arr: [{id: "123",
         value: "First"},
        {id: "456",
         value: "Second"}]
};
```

I tried using _.merge(dest, src) (using Lodash) and a couple of other methods, but seems like the 2nd object is overwriting the first one because it doesn't handle the nested array the way I want.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: `dest.arr = _.merge(dest.arr,src.arr)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Lodash [_.mergeWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#mergeWith) method:

```
var dest = {
  id: "865",
  arr: [{
    id: "123",
    value: "First"
  }]
};

var src = {
  id: "865",
  arr: [{
    id: "456",
    value: "Second"
  }]

};

var merge = _.mergeWith({}, src, dest, function(a, b) {
  if (_.isArray(a)) {
    return b.concat(a);
  }
});
console.log(merge);
```

It allows you to pass a customizer in order to merge the array in a "custom" way.

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n2s83pgw/1/). Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! This was what I was looking for.

Comment: @GavinAng Glad to hear it. Please, accept the answer if it's ok with you, thanks!

Comment: how would this have to change if I need to merge based on the id field in top level (ie. id=865). I realize the above doesn't work if both the src and dest are arrays of objects and I am trying to merge based on id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.assign()`

```js
var dest = {
  id: "865",
  arr: [{
    id: "123",
    value: "First" }]
};

var src = {
  id: "865",
  arr: [{
    id: "456",
    value: "Second" }]

};

var merge = Object.assign({}, dest);
merge.arr.push(Object.assign({}, src.arr[0]));

src.arr[0].id = 789; // should not affect `merge.arr`

console.log(merge);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any libraries.

```js
    var dest = {
      id: "865",
      arr: [{
        id: "123",
        value: "First"
      }]
    };

    var src = {
      id: "865",
      arr: [{
        id: "456",
        value: "Second"
      }]

    };

    // 1
    var resultOne = {
      id: dest.id,
      arr: src.arr.concat(dest.arr)
    };

    // 2
    var resultTwo = Object.assign({}, src, {
      arr: src.arr.concat(dest.arr)
    });


    // 3
    var merge = function(obj1, obj2) {
      return Object.keys(obj1).reduce(function(result, next) {
        if (Array.isArray(obj1[next]) && Array.isArray(obj2[next])) {
          result[next] = obj1[next].concat(obj2[next]);
        } else if (obj1[next] && obj2[next]) {
          result[next] = obj2[next];
        }
        return result;
      }, {});
    }

    console.log(merge(src, dest));
```